# I am modelling a human, and need to split the legs

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am modelling a human, and need to split the legs. Can someone help me?

Note: I am aware that there are plenty of ways to model a human. My question is basically how to take one mesh, and be able to slice it like how we slice a cake. The once empty region of the mesh should be replaced with two planes in the same position.

My simplified blender file [image]

[image]

Comment: From this, I think the easiest is to select the edges along the legs from bottom to crotch and delete them.

Comment: very original question! I tried but can't find a simple way to do that. For future reference, since humans are symmetrical it's easier to model them using a mirror modifier

Comment: @wilks Thanks! But currently I am modelling the woman in the reference photo doing an asymmetrical pose.

Comment: @AnnZen would you mind sharing a simplified version of the [file in question](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)? You may just add it as an [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/195048/edit) so that it is visible to anyone, (many users don't read the comments) thanks :)

Comment: @Timaroberts Do you mean the blender file or image reference?

Comment: @AnnZen I was referring to the .blend file, but both would likely be useful for most users that would like to try answering :)

Comment: @Timaroberts Thanks!

Comment: There are several ways to rip model edges... but I'm not sure the simplified model allows a similar approach to the real one above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the edges you want to split.

[image]

2. Press V to split them and move them away slightly.

[image]

Then repeat for the back of the leg.

3. Join two edges by selecting them and pressing F.

[image]

4. Fill in the rest of the faces by selecting the end edge and pressing F multiple times.

[image]

[image]

Then you can add more edge loops with Ctrl+R and with the "Loop Tools" addon enabled, you can also relax edge loops or even make them circles or evenly spaced. (Relax, Space, Circle)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The .blend file you provided does not have the same geometry, but this should be adaptable. Select the middle edges/vertices as shown in the picture. In the .blend you provided, this is as simple as alt clicking on an edge. In your real model, it may involve a bit more finagling to get the selection where you want. You can select multiple edges/verts by holding shift and clicking, or holding ctrl to get the shortest distance between two points. You could also use the circle, box, or lasso select for this. Anyways,[image: Middle vertices/edges selected]

delete them x > delete vertices

[image]

select a region of edges/vertices and press 'F' to fill in a face. This may be more or less difficult depending on how symetrical the front/back topology of the model is. Its the least painful when there are the same number of edges. [image]

[image]

Not sure why those images got out of order, or how to fix them. Sorry about that.

Fill in the rest of the faces, if you need more resolution in the middle areas, use the ring tool, 'ctrl+R', or knife tool 'K' You can peel back the sides with proportional editing 'O' turned on, make sure to hide the other leg, or turn on connected only, so you don't drag it along. You could also switch to sculpt mode and use the smooth tool. [image]
This image uses sculpt mode smooth.

[image]

This is the same process but without deleting the vertices ALL way up.
There's no one way to do things in modeling, this is your little world and you can do it however you like. That said, it would be much more efficient to make your legs split from the start, than to make them one block and split them later.

Comment: Thanks, but I want a single split, like the end result should have 2 planes in the same place.

Comment: Then just select all the faces in the middle and press S > x > 0 (or y or z if you're not modeling the front on the front axis for whatever reason). You could also just use a boolean, which could create a very perfect slice, the geometry would be even messier, but it seems like that's what you're going for anyways.

Answer (score 2):

From the given blend file, I think a quick way to do it is to:

- Split the bottom horizontal face, between feet. To do that, select vertices at the extremities and use <kbd>J</kbd> to join them along a new edge.

[image]

- Then, we can select the legs middle and use the *"split > face by edges"* menu:

[image]

- Now we have two separated parts, so that we can select the boundary edges and use <kbd>F</kbd> to close them by a face (have moved them appart here for explanation purpose):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are in wrong way of modeling . you should start from a basic

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

and you should to follow the Topology like this :

[image]

By adding modifier Mirror build your model Symmetrize
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I made an edit to clarify things.